# What is EditText callback when text changes its HTML representation

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am aware of `addTextChangedListener` but it is not good.

I use `EditText` as a simple rich text editor, user can edit bold, italic, underlined, text color.
I get the user entered text with `Html.toHtml(...)`

Problem:

```
public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        setContentView(editText);
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.e("", ""+Html.toHtml(s));
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}    

}
```

When the user enters `abcd test` (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/61DLu.png ), the `Html.toHtml` will be `<p>abcd <u><font color ="#78000000">test</font></u></p>`, which is not good, because the user did not enter it as underlined half-transparent text.

Is there a callback when the html representation is also finalized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to remove the composing markup from the text so now it does not have the underline and transparency:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    SpannableStringBuilder s2 = new SpannableStringBuilder(s);
    removeComposingSpans(s2);
    Log.e("", ""+Html.toHtml(s2));
}

public static void removeComposingSpans(Spannable s) {
    Object[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), Object.class);
    for (Object object : spans) {
        int flags = s.getSpanFlags(object);
        if ((flags & Spannable.SPAN_COMPOSING) > 0) {
            s.removeSpan(object);
        }
    }
}
```